# Is entropy of a system, strongly coupled with another one, well defined?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Consider two, strongly coupled systems, $A$, and $B$, and suppose to be interested to the entropy of $A$.

The Boltzmann definition of entropy, for A, is $S_A=k_B \ln (\Omega_A)$, where $\Omega_A$ is the number of accessible microstates, of A, compatible with the macrostate in which A is in.

I think that, this definition of entropy, for $A$,  can't be applied, indeed, if $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian of the total system, $A+B$, we can write: $\hat H= \hat H_B + \hat H_B + \hat H_{AB}$, where, $\hat H_{AB}$, the coupling term between $A$ and $B$, can't be neglected.

So, the microstates of the total system, can't be factorized out, namely, $\psi(A,B)\neq \psi_A(x_A) \psi_B(x_B)$. For this reason, we can't speak about microstates of $A$, and microstates of B, we can only speak about microstates of the total system, $A+B$. If follows that, $\Omega_A$, is not well defined too, and the same for $S_A$.

Does this idea makes any sense to you?

Comment: Are A and B in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Comment: No, they are not. However, I think that, there is a problem, in distinguish between microstates of $A$ and microstates of $B$, also if they are at equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is why the usual rules of thermodynamics and statistical physics apply on to macroscopic systems whose energy of interaction with the environment is negligible to total energy. This is true for contact interactions (heat transfer, pressure), but not for the Coulomb or gravity interaction.

Also, in quantum statistical physics we usually don't work with the concept of $\Omega$ as the number of states $\psi$ compatible with macrostate $A$, that set is hard to work with mathematically. Instead, usually only special states are counted in $\Omega$, such as all the different eigenstates of some chosen set of commuting operators (Hamiltonian) compatible with the macrostate.